# How are elements in the sigma algebra of product of measurable spaces

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Is there a general form for an element in the sigma algebra of the product of mesurable spaces, and if there is on, how is it?

If we have mesurable spaces $(X, \mathcal{M})$, $(Y, \mathcal{N})$ we have the definition for the product sigma-algebra:

$$\mathcal{M} \otimes  \mathcal{N} = \sigma( \{ A\times B | A \in  \mathcal{M}\text{ and }  B \in  \mathcal{N} \})$$

Then i was wondering how a general element looks in here, i had the idea that was the union ( posibly infinite) of rectangles ($ A \times B$ ). But it doesnt seams to catch the complemet part needed for the sigma-algebra

Comment: Is there necessarily a general form? There is no necessarily a nice general form for sets in a generated sigma algebra.

Comment: Maybe there isnt. I should refrased my question